# add powerpoint 2010 effect in vba (grow/shrink)

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

overall idea is user selects something from a drop down, then a shape grows based on their selection.  I am able to get the dropdown and identify which shape I need the grow / shrink on, but not able to add the grow.

```
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
Dim myShape As Shape

myShape = myDocument.Shapes("Illinois")

Dim oEffect As Effect

Set oEffect = myDocument.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(Shape:=myShape,     effectid:=msoAnimEffectGrowShrink)

With oEffect
.EffectParameters.Size = 30
.EffectType = msoAnimEffectGrowShrink
.Timing.Duration = 2
End With
```

The error is Object Variable  or With block not set.
Thanks!

Comment: which line raises the error?

Comment: looks like on this statement myShape = myDocument.Shapes("Illinois"). there is a shape in there called "illinois" though (prior to this I had a statement that called"flip" and it executed fine). statements such as myDocument.Shapes("Illinois").Height also execute fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `myShape` is an object variable, you need to use the `Set` keyword when assigning to it.

`Set myShape = myDocument.Shapes("Illinois")`

> statements such as myDocument.Shapes("Illinois").Height also execute fine

That's because the `.Height` is a non-object property which is assigned without the keyword, for example you may have assigned to the `.Height` like so:

```
myDocument.Shapes("Illinois").height = 300
```

But when referring to the shape itself, you do need it as an object with the `Set` keyword.